# Which is the best way to restrict access to certain pages in my website to certain users other than admin using cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a website where all the pages are accessible to the public except for one Releases page which is user specific or maybe to a specific group .I have a seperate login page to gain access to 'Releases' page based on authentication.How do I go about this?Using Acl or Authorize function?I am very confused..Also do i need to use the same users table for authenticating this page, in that case do I use this User login page as an elemnt in my other login page.Could somebody please hint me on how to proceed?

Comment: Try to prevent ACL, as it is usually overhead. If it works for you try [Tiny](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL is overkill for many situations.

What I normally do is something like this in my controller:

```
public function releases() {

    $this->_allowedGroups(array(1,2,3));

    // rest of code here

}
```

Then in my app controller:

```
public function _allowedGroups($groups=array()) {

    if( !in_array($this->Auth->user('group_id'), $groups) ) {

       $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login'));

    }


}
```

Comment: Agreed. I usually create a function in AppController which takes 3 arguments: an identifier defining the type of **object** (articles, groups, images, users, you name it), the **ID** of said object, and finally the **action** I want to perform, which is usually one of the four CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete). Obviously the ID is null for Create.

Comment: If I have 3 groups of people-                                                        1:admin who has access to front end as well as back end 2: staff who has access to Releases page as well as other front end pages 3:Users who have access to all front end pages other than Releases, will this section of code in my  app controller work

Comment: You should be able to adapt the above. All you need to do in your "special case" controller methods is supply the group_ids that can access that resource in $this->_allowedGroups(array(...));

Comment: if($this->Auth->user('group_id') == 1){
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }elseif($this->Auth->user('group_id') == 2 ){
        $this->Auth->allow('all the other pages except releases');
    }elseif($this->Auth->user(group_id==3)){
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Acl should do your work. 
And is there any specific need that you are using a separate login page??

A single login page and and a single users table should suffice your needs if you implement acl. Only those users who have rights to view the Requests page will be allowed to do so.

Comment: I have another page  and login is a part of that page which gives access to Releases page rather than clicking on Releases page and then giving a user login  to help login..I used Acl but it was not working fine and allowing anyone to access any page despite all teh allow and deny permissions

Comment: Maybe you should add the issues you are facing  with ACL as a different question then and get is solved

Answer (score 0):

you may do something like this..

on core.php, put

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('release'));
```

and do the verification on the AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller{
    public function beforeFilter(){
        if (isset($this->params['prefix']) and $this->params['prefix'] == 'release'){
            if ($this->Session->read("User.type") != 'admin'){
                    //redirect the user or throw an error...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so,  youdomain.com/release/* will only be accesible by your administrators...

also, i don't see why you need two logins pages... you could just put a flag on your users table saying if the user is or not an admin... and on the login, set the User.type property on session.

if you don't need of complex permissions control, i think you don't need use ACL.

Comment: I need a few users other than admin to be able to see the pages, so I should have two groups, admin who has access to all the pages including backend and maybe staff who have access to all pages and releases page exludind the admin pages while the public gets access to all front end pages other than releases